# keyboard Events

Tags: c#

whenever i am pressing key in my server system i ll send that keyevent  to another system after that the  correspondingaction should be  happend in the client machine.. help me to get a better way to solve this problem

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly then what you have doesn't sound too bad.  Are you saying that:

- You have a client server architecture.
- At the server (presumably at command console or management application) you press a key.
- The key corresponds to an action.  The action needs to be invoked at the client.

You could implement this using asynchronous WCF.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353383/beginners-wcf-question-consumable-asynchronous-services) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400798/how-to-make-a-call-to-my-wcf-service-asynchronous) for more some more info.  One way to look at this problem is as a distributed observer pattern.  Your server is the subject and the client(s) are the observer(s).

---

Update: Handling Key Events in .Net

You could try adding a KeyDown event handler to your form:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Ctrl + C pressed" );
        // Swallow key event, i.e. indicate that it was handled.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But if you have any controls on your form then you won't get the event.  What you probably need to do is sniff windows messages using a message filter.  E.g.

```
public class KeyDownMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Key Down
            return true; // Event handled
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add this message filter to the application using the [AddMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) method.  If you want to check if the CTRL key is pressed for the key down message then check the [lparam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx).

If any of this isn't clear then let me know.

Comment: can you tell me how to get combination of key from my application like Ctrl+c Ctrl+v etc....

Answer (score 1):

please give us more details on what you're trying to do.
To simulate key presses in Windows Forms, I'd use SendKeys class.

Comment: how to use send value thru SendKeys